# How can i check if listbox is connected to a datasource?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

theres a way to check if listbox is connected to datascource ?

I mean something like that

```
if (listbox1.datascource.enabled == true)
....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes just test for

```
if (listbox1.DataSource != null)
```

This could be easily discovered looking at the reference material for everything NET related

[MSDN on Listbox.DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: how I didnt think about it.. Thanks !.

And I have another question (if I can ask) , there's a way to refresh listbox datasoruce ?. I mean without to use an sql query again..

Comment: @ShmulikCohen: For which purpose? What do you want to achieve by refreshing a data source, if you are not going to refresh the data?